# Dataframe object is no callable

Tags: python, pandas

I am applying a style to a DataFrame, but when I call the method `'mask_r'`, I Have an Error, like this: `DataFrame Object is no Callable`

I am passing the Dataframe to the function, and the I am  applying the style to that DataFrame.

this is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

class data:
    
    def __init__(self, Data = pd.DataFrame, value = int, DataC = pd.DataFrame):
        self.Data = Data
        self.value = value
        self.DataC = DataC
    
        
    @classmethod
    def create_dataframes(self):
        Random = np.random.randn(6)
        Random_2 = np.random.randn(6)
        Random_choise = np.random.randint(5, size=(6))
        Date_Data = pd.DataFrame(["2021-02-01","2021-02-02","2021-02-03","2021-02-04","2021-02-05","2021-02-06"],columns={"D"})
        Data = pd.DataFrame(Random_choise, columns=["A"])
        Data = pd.concat([Data, pd.DataFrame(Random, columns=list("B"))],axis=1)
        Data = pd.concat([Data, pd.DataFrame(Random_2, columns=list("C"))],axis=1)
        Data = pd.concat([Data, pd.DataFrame(Date_Data, columns=list("D"))],axis=1)
        self.Data = Data
        self.DataC  = Data.copy()
        return Data
 

    @classmethod
    def boolean_exploration(self):
        Data = self.Data
        return Data[["B"]]<0
    
    
    @classmethod
    def masking(self):
        yellow = "background-color:yellow"
        mask= self.Data["B"]<0
        d = pd.DataFrame('', self.Data.index, self.Data.columns)
        d.loc[mask,:] = yellow
        return d
        
    @classmethod   
    def mask_r(self): 
        masking = self.masking()
        maskdata = self.Data.style.apply(masking, axis=None,subset=["B"])
        return maskdata
```

why I am Getting that error?

Answer (score 0):

I figure out:

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
class data:

```
def __init__(self, Data = pd.DataFrame, value = int, DataC = pd.DataFrame):
    self.Data = Data
    self.value = value
    self.DataC = DataC

    
@classmethod
def create_dataframes(self):
    Random = np.random.randn(6)
    Random_2 = np.random.randn(6)
    Random_choise = np.random.randint(5, size=(6))
    Date_Data = pd.DataFrame(["2021-02-01","2021-02-02","2021-02-03","2021-02-04","2021-02-05","2021-02-06"],columns={"D"})
    Data = pd.DataFrame(Random_choise, columns=["A"])
    Data = pd.concat([Data, pd.DataFrame(Random, columns=list("B"))],axis=1)
    Data = pd.concat([Data, pd.DataFrame(Random_2, columns=list("C"))],axis=1)
    Data = pd.concat([Data, pd.DataFrame(Date_Data, columns=list("D"))],axis=1)
    self.Data = Data
    self.DataC  = Data.copy()
    return Data


@classmethod
def boolean_exploration(self):
    Data = self.Data
    return Data[["B"]]<0


def masking(x):
    yellow = "background-color:yellow"
    mask= x["B"]<0
    d = pd.DataFrame('', x.index,x.columns)
    d.loc[mask,:] = yellow
    return d



    
@staticmethod
def mask_r(): 
    maskdata = data.create_dataframes().style.apply(masking, axis=None,subset=["B"])
    return maskdata
```

Answer (score 0):

Do as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


class data:
    
    def __init__(self, Data = pd.DataFrame):
        self.Data = Data
   

        
    @classmethod
    def create_dataframes(self):
        Random = np.random.randn(6)
        Random_2 = np.random.randn(6)
        Random_choise = np.random.randint(5, size=(6))
        Date_Data = pd.DataFrame(["2021-02-01","2021-02-02",
                                  "2021-02-03","2021-02-04","2021-02-05","2021-02-06"],columns={"D"})
        Data = pd.DataFrame(Random_choise, columns=["A"])
        Data = pd.concat([Data, pd.DataFrame(Random, columns=list("B"))],axis=1)
        Data = pd.concat([Data, pd.DataFrame(Random_2, columns=list("C"))],axis=1)
        Data = pd.concat([Data, pd.DataFrame(Date_Data, columns=list("D"))],axis=1)
        self.Data = Data
        return Data
 

    @classmethod
    def boolean_exploration(self):
        Data = self.Data
        return Data[["B"]]<0
    
    
    def mask_y(x):
        yellow = "background-color:yellow"
        mask= x["B"]<0
        d = pd.DataFrame('', x.index,x.columns)
        d.loc[mask,:] = yellow
        return d
    
    
    def mask_g(x):
        green = "background-color:#81df81"
        mask= x["A"]>0
        d = pd.DataFrame('', x.index, x.columns)
        d.loc[mask,:] = green
        return d
    
    
    
    def mask_o_y(x):
        yellow = "background-color:yellow"
        orange = "background-color:#F5C48F"
        mask= x["B"]<0
        mask2= x["B"]>0
        d = pd.DataFrame('', x.index, x.columns)
        d.loc[mask,:] = yellow
        d.loc[mask2,:] = orange
        return d
    
       
    @staticmethod
    def apply_mask_y(): 
        return data.create_dataframes().style.apply(data.mask_y, axis=None,subset=["B"])
    
    
    @staticmethod
    def apply_mask_g(): 
        return data.create_dataframes().style.apply(data.mask_g, axis=None,subset=["A"])
       
        
    @staticmethod
    def apply_mask_o_y(): 
        return data.create_dataframes().style.apply(data.mask_o_y, axis=None,subset=["B"])
    
    
    
    @classmethod
    def background_yellow(self):
        return self.Data.loc[self.Data["B"]<0].style.set_properties(**{'background-color': 'yellow'} ,subset=['B'])
    
    
    
    @classmethod
    def background_yellow_lambda_exp(self):
        yellow =  self.Data.loc[lambda x : x["B"]<0].style.set_properties(**{'background-color': 'yellow'} ,subset=['B'])
        return yellow
  

    def background_values(x):
        color=''
        if x < 0:
            color = 'background-color:yellow'
            return color
        if x >= 2:
            color = 'background-color:red'
            return color
        if x > 0:
            color = 'background-color:#F5C48F'
            return color
        if x == 0:
            color = 'background-color:orange'
            return color

    @staticmethod
    def apply_mask_background_colors():
        return data.create_dataframes().style.applymap(data.background_values,subset=["A","B","C"])
```